# Using a trigger to alter an existing row when a row with a duplicate key is added in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table called `jobs` in a MySQL database.

One user adds data by importing an Excel file into a linked table in Access.

This works fine, except occasionally, there is a row with a duplicate id.

What I would like to do when this happens is take the data from one column (`comments`) of the new row and insert it into the existing row with the identical id.

For example, the original table:

```
id    customer    product    comments
1     Jeff        Widget     Hello
2     Fred        Sprocket   Important comment here
```

Some imported data:

```
id    customer    product    comments
2     Fred                   A new and different comment
3     Jerry       Widget     More comments
```

The table after importing the above data:

```
id    customer    product    comments
1     Jeff        Widget     Hello
2     Fred        Sprocket   A new and different comment
3     Jerry       Widget     More comments
```

I'm at a loss as to how to build a trigger that would achieve this goal.

Any advice?

EDIT: Opted to use a PHP script to clean up the duplicates after the fact. Thanks for the input, all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience with Access linked tables, this can only be done with code or a two-step query process.  First inserting the new records, and then performing an update operation with the remainder of the data set (you could do it in the opposite order as well).  Is this something you need to do on an ongoing basis, or just a one time deal?

Comment: It's a daily ordeal... The issue is that Access will blindly Insert all of the records.

It occurs to me that rather than try to intercept the duplicate data, I could instead try running an event through an after insert trigger to clean up the duplicates.

Comment: Just thought I'd add that Access shouldn't add duplicate data (and won't update the other columns) if it correctly understands, or is made to believe, the index columns of the table it's linked to.  If you can import the indexed columns in the table definition, it should prevent the blind insertion.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) may be of help.

As I understand it, you run an and `INSERT` statement and tell MySQL what to `UPDATE` when a duplicate key is inserted.

So, your table insert statement would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO mysqlTable (id,customer,product,comment)
SELECT id,customer,product,comment FROM linkedTable
  WHERE x = y
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE comment = linkedTable.comment;
```

Comment: Stop me if I'm just being ignorant, but my assumption is that there is not a way to alter the way Access Inserts data into the linked MySQL table. Thus, my hope is that there is a way to intercept duplicates with a Before Insert Trigger, rather than creating an Insert script.

Comment: @Chris Oh, I see. Sorry, I thought you meant that they were updating an Access table and then you were copying that table into a MySQL table. I've never used the linking capabilities of Access.

Comment: Which brings us back to my question: Can this instead be done with a Trigger, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using REPLACE INTO. But also, you have to be careful with REPLACE INTO as it actually deletes the previous entry and starts a new row.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently using mssql. I ran an update first. After that I ran the insert on what was left. I have never worked with access and quite frankly don't want to.

```
update table1 set comments = (select comments from table2 where table2.id = table1.id) where table1.id in (select table2.id from table2);

insert into table1 (customer,product,comments) select customer, product, comments from table2 where table2.id not in (select table1.id from table1);
```

Not sure if you can do joins on the insert and update like you can in mssql/t-sql

Hope it helps